# Do PDO transactions block until all other transactions are committed?

Tags: mysql, database, pdo

If I am correct, PDO transactions are not really transactions: they merely turn off autocommits (See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php)).

So if I have a transaction A which deletes a row and transaction B which modifes the same row, the following could happen.

1. Transaction A starts and turns off autocommit.
2. Transaction B starts and turns off autocommit.
3. Transaction A deletes a row.
4. Transaction B modifies the same row.
5. Transaction A finishes and commits changes.
6. Transaction B finishes and commits changes.

But at step 6, the row has been already deleted in step 5. What would happen?

Also, how can I make sure to let Transaction B to block until Transaction A is committed? FYI, I am using PDO with mysql with innoDB.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you perceive to be the difference between "a transaction" and "a statement that is not autocommitted"?  They are the same thing.  In step 3, when transaction A deletes the row, MySQL will place "an exclusive lock" on that row until the transaction is committed or rolled back; therefore transaction B will wait at step 4 until step 5 has taken place.

Comment: I thought transactions automatically block its execution until all other transactions which potentially modify the same rows are all committed. I may be wrong.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/commit.html

Comment: I see, so I was wrong. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @eggyal pointed out, transactions can occur at the same time but a DELETE statment puts an exclusive lock on the row until the transaction is committed, so Transaction B will automatically block at step 4 until Transaction A is committed. An exclusive lock block all writes and also reads.